Weird looking sine wave behavior in an electric circuit
while studying an RLC circuit I noticed some weird like sine waves  at low frequencies (1-9 kHertz) on the inductor,
The amplitude behavior did not follow the theoretical model. Instead, suggested the presence of two distinct frequencies:
One being a main sinusoidal signal and another influencing smaller sinusoidal or cosine-like variations on the waveform.
In order to add more clarity ,here are the components used the resistor used is 470 ohm the inductor is 20.71mH the capacitor 0.937nF , and just like how RLC circuits are usually studied we used a signal generator that generates an Ac voltage and got the following results from the oscilloscope for low frequencies
for high values the circuit acted as expected
Is there a physical intuition for what could be causing this? it feels like that there might be something caused from the high pace filter and the frequency of the Ac voltage provider .








it should be noted when reading the legend the names are according to the colour  of the measurements not of the fit


Is the higher frequency $60$ Hz? Sometimes a power supply does not perfectly filter out the AC power from the wall.

the device that provides ac voltage connected to the Oscilloscope used had frequencies between 1hz to 100khz if I remember correctly I think I have the manual of the device I can check  the range I dealt with was for the data given 2.2khz  2,5khz and 8.8 khz

When your sin is weird, you must repent.

You might also try proper capitalization and punctuation, if you want to get some answers. It's easier to answer questions that are not annoying to read. (Just my opinion, I guess.)

@hft actually I appreciate it , this is my weak spot when posting questions  even  when I edit them exactly after posting to fix punctuation I seem to put them in the wrong places, seems like I really need to read a dozen of good questions from here to get how to do this , I have reedited feel free to pinpoint the annoying parts so I can notice  what to be careful with

OK, a few suggestions. We use the three-letter notation $\sin$ to denote a sine function when writing math equations. But, the English name of the function is "sine," not "sin." Sentences should start with capital letters. (At least two of yours still don't). Sentences should end with a punctuation mark. (At least one of yours still doesn't).

Also, one of the comments on this question asked for clarification regarding 60 Hz signals. If you could somehow clarify the figures to show the different periods that might help. The plots don't seem to have any units on the horizontal axes, so it is hard to tell what a 60 Hz signal would look like.

thank you this is helpful I will go and name the graphs add units and apply the suggestions you gave

Are you trying to drive a low impedance RLC circuit from a signal generator? My guess is that your generator's output amplifier can't handle the load.

the resistor used is 470 ohm the  inductor is 20.71mH the capacitor  0.937nF is this considered low impedance RLC circuit  ?

for the rest indeed i used a signal generator to study the behaviour of an RLC circuit and got the results from the oscilloscope

Please reopen this post as I think that what has been asked is clear and I can give an interesting? quantitative answer.

With competent values that you have given and assuming that the voltage source has little or no resistance then $Q=10$ and the resonant frequency is $\approx 36\,\rm kHz$.
As the $Q$ value is relatively large that resonant frequency is approximately the same if you were monitoring the voltage across the resistor (current resonance) or across the capacitor (charge resonance).
Now look at your CRO traces.

Five of your traces are for frequencies below resonance and one above.
The next thing to note is your voltage scale showing that the response of the circuit increases as one gets closer to the resonant frequency.
Now to the frequency of the "noise".
For the $2.2\,\rm kHz$ trace I counted approximately 80 peaks over five periods of the voltage source frequency which indicates that the noise frequency is approximately $80/5\times 2.2 = 35\,\rm kHz$.
Doing the same for the $3.6\,\rm kHz$ trace gives the frequency of the noise as $30/3\times 3.6 = 36\,\rm kHz$, ie the same as the first trace.
So what I suggest is happening is that somewhere internal or external to the voltage source there is a source at a frequency of approximately $36\rm \, kHz$ which is "amplified" by the tuned circuit.
However as the frequency of the voltage supply is increased the response of the tuned circuit to that frequency is increased and the voltage supply signal amplitude becomes more and more significant relative to amplitude of the noise signal.
Finally I think that the noise seen on the $49.4\,\rm kHz$ trace is due to local radio frequency signals, possibly from a radio station?

actually really interesting take I appreciate going into how you calculated the frequency of the noise ,I am not really familiar with noise but does it usually have this high frequency or is this not considered high , from my point of view being this much higher than the resonance frequency is quite unexpected probably because of my level

secondly what is the difference between radio station noise and normal noise , this is quite interesting yet I can't truly comprehend some of the concepts,

I can comprehed the high pass filter making the amplitude of the noise low and I understand that if it is frequency is high enough it won't be totally blocked or filtered

The first bit of noise is at/near the resonant frequency of the circuit and has been uplifted in amplitude by the resonant circuit. Radio frequencies will be much higher in frequency.  You can “see” it on a cro by having a high gain /,sensitive setting on the y-input which is connected to a lead which is not terminated at the other end.

this answer is pretty satisfying I think what is still confusing me is why is the amplitude of noise changing on the amplitude of the the frequency I am providing , like why did it oscillate in this manner but other than that you seem to have answered the question , I just  keep it until tomorrow , to see other point of views if there is ,

thank you a lot , this is fun to read and  improves intution

I suspect that the signal generator is struggling to produce the lower frequencies you used in your tests and is not driving your circuit with a true sine wave, but with something looking like a truncated sine wave.
I recommend isolating the signal generator from the test circuit with a series (current-limiting) resistor so you can measure the purity of the signal source separately from the voltages in your circuit.
I also recommend using a dual-trace scope with the output of the sig gen on one channel and the system response on the other, synchronized in time.

I will ask my lab instructor for extra hours in the laboratory to test the possible causes you mentioned and hopefully return with answers ,thanks for the recommendations on how to do the testing , I will begin with checking if I get the same results building the circuit again , and then check the signal generator

just for how to isolate the signal generator from the test circuit , so I do not connect the the signal generator to a resistor out side the circuit , instead I add another resistor to the existing circuit and measure the current on it

before doing this I have the 470ohm resistor data I went and checked if I measured the amplitude at low frequencies I have 2 saved out_puts  I will add them above
